# install node rest client

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I get this error:

```
 var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client; //Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I was trying to install it according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client but I do not understand the installation part

How to install it? I am trying to run this https://github.com/flightaware/flightxml3_examples/tree/master/javascript/rest/node

Comment: Are you trying to run it in a browser ?

Comment: How do you actually run your script ? What version of Node.js are you using ?

Comment: You need Node to run the example you're trying.

Comment: So I downloaded node and what do I do next please?

Comment: I downloaded 6.11.4 LTS version